# Program type already present: android.support.v13.view.DragStartHelper$1

Tags: android, android-studio

Ive been searching for the solution of this error since yesterday. I tried everything. I deleted my .idea and .gradle file. I even invalidate cache and restart my android studio. I also re-install my android studio but to no avail. I am still getting this error. I didn't touch my project for about a month. When I came back. I updated my android studio and tried to run my project and was greeted with this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
     Program type already present: android.support.v13.view.DragStartHelper$1
```

I had multidex enabled on my gradle. A month ago I don't have this problem. Right after updating my android studio I got this. Anyone have a solution? All the libraries I am using should be fine as I was able to release my app without having this error a month ago.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Okay. So after careful reading from other who had this problem, I needed to exclude the support v13 on gradle following the link [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-find-dependencies-particular-dependency-gradle-hesamedin-kamalan-1/)

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
}
```

Comment: This feels super hacky, but thankfully it worked for me!

Comment: @MalwinderSingh did you able to find solution?

Answer (score 15):

I couldn't comment because my reputation but the answer below worked fine. The unique add note I recommend is where put it.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
    }
    ...
}
```

Further details about how exclude dependencies [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-find-dependencies-particular-dependency-gradle-hesamedin-kamalan-1/)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced with same problem. In my case:

1. I excluded in my project
   `import android.support.v13.app.ActivityCompat`
   and changed to
   `import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat`
   and rewrote my code with support v4
2. Next I added in my project:

   ```
    android { 
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "ru.android.company.myproject"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 30
            ... 
    } 
        ...  
        configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
        } 
        ...
        }
   ```

It's solution is working for me.